# How to write json content to jsp table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I have to write a ajax callback function, in which I have json object , When I test with alert it shows `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. Here each object contain 6 variables. I have to display each obj values in each row . How can I do this.

Here is my code,

```
xmlHttpReqRM.open('POST', "RTMonitor?rtype=rmonitor&clientid="+<%=uid%>, true);
xmlHttpReqRM.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  if (xmlHttpReqRM.readyState == 4) {
  if (xmlHttpReqRM.status == 200) {
  var responceeString = xmlHttpReqRM.responseText;
  var jsonobj= JSON.parse(xmlHttpReqRM.responseText);
  alert(jsonobj);
```

my jsp table is like this,

```
<div id="tab1">  
    <table id="flexme1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="140"><h3>VehicleNo</h3></td>
                <td width="140"><h3>Latitude</h3></td>
                <td width="140"><h3>Longitude</h3></td>
                <td width="140"><h3>Status</h3></td>
                <td width="140"><h3>RDate</h3></td>
                <td width="140"><h3>RTime</h3></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I do this can any one help me.

Comment: Never `alert()` an object. Always use `console.dir()` for it. Check the object contents in the console and parse accordingly.

Comment: @indieblue it showa Array[3] and inside of it shows all values in object.

Comment: Do you want those 3 values in that table?

Comment: yes. exactly. . it is array of 3 objects , each object has 6 values. I want each object values in each row.

Comment: @indieblue do you knw how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that might help you add rows to the table:

```
jsonobj.forEach(function(item){  // item = 1 object with 6 values
  $('#flexme1 > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+item[0]+'</td><td>'+item[1]+'</td><td>'+item[2]+'</td><td>'+item[3]+'</td><td>'+item[4]+'</td><td>'+item[5]+'</td></tr>');
});
```

You can add this code in place of `alert(jsonobj);`.

Comment: in alert it is showing `undefined` in place of `item[]`